# why 1337 uid in laravel sail?

Tags: laravel

Inside the Laravel-Sail dockerfile you can find the following line.

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail
```

Which adds a user with 1337 UID. However, no user can be found with the mentioned id after build and all files and directories have `1337` as user instead of `sail`. I think perhaps the correct way would be to use `1000` instead of `1337`.

[image]

Why laravel sail developers using 1337 UID?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet

Comment: the `-u` parameter sets a numerical value for the user id of the user. The number just needs to be unique but other than that it can be whatever so the devs of Sail decided it would be "leet" to use 1337 I guess. The user name created is still `sail`